# Assigning values of words in a dictionary to dataframe contents

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

The following is an example of a dataframe, a dictionary, and a code that works, but **is extremely inefficient for huge dictionaries**. One of the columns of the dataframe contains sentences. The code takes every word from the sentence, checks if it's in the dictionary and assigns its value to it. The mean of the values (per sentence, or row) is calculated and saved in an extra column.

```
import pandas as pd
    test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    '_id': ['1a','2b','3c','4d'],
    'column': ['und der in zu',
                'Kompliziertereswort something',
                'Lehrerin in zu [Buch]',
                'Buch (Lehrerin) kompliziertereswort']})

{'und': 20,
     'der': 10,
     'in':  40,
     'zu':  10,
     'Kompliziertereswort': 2,
     'Buch': 5,
     'Lehrerin': 5}

pat = fr"\b({'|'.join(map(re.escape, d))})\b"
test_df['score'] = test_df['column'].str.extractall(pat)[0].map(d).mean(level=0)

print(test_df)

  _id                               column  score
0  1a                        und der in zu   20.0
1  2b        Kompliziertereswort something    2.0
2  3c                Lehrerin in zu [Buch]   15.0
3  4d  Buch (Lehrerin) kompliziertereswort    5.0
```

Since going through a dictionary is more efficient than using regex, I believe there has to a way to **do it using a function that splits the sentences into words and just checks if they're in the dictionary and computes the average**. I also transformed the dictionary into a dataframe and used explode(), but again that is not efficient at all.

Comment: Have you try to profile your code? If yes what is most time consuming part of processing?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is `split` values to words, convert to Series, remove punctuation, mapping and last aggregate `mean`:

```
import string

test_df['score'] = (test_df['column'].str.split(expand=True)
                                     .stack()
                                     .str.strip(string.punctuation)
                                     .map(d)
                                     .groupby(level=0)
                                     .mean())
print(test_df)
  _id                               column  score
0  1a                        und der in zu   20.0
1  2b        Kompliziertereswort something    2.0
2  3c                Lehrerin in zu [Buch]   15.0
3  4d  Buch (Lehrerin) kompliziertereswort    5.0
```

Or is possible use `dict.get` for mapping splitted values:

```
f = lambda x: np.nanmean([d.get(y, np.nan) for y in x.split()])
test_df['score'] = test_df['column'].str.replace('[^\w\s]','', regex=True).apply(f)
  _id                               column  score
0  1a                        und der in zu   20.0
1  2b        Kompliziertereswort something    2.0
2  3c                Lehrerin in zu [Buch]   15.0
3  4d  Buch (Lehrerin) kompliziertereswort    5.0
```

Alternative:

```
f = lambda x: np.nanmean([d.get(y, np.nan) for y in x])
test_df['score'] = test_df['column'].str.split(r'\W').apply(f)
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one works but for the bigger dataset it throws DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. Could there be an error in the values of the dictionaries?

Comment: @johnnydoe - can you try `.stack().astype(str)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
test_df['score'] = test_df['column'].str.split(r'\W').explode() \
                                    .map(d).groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Output:

```
>>> test_df

  _id                               column  score
0  1a                        und der in zu   20.0
1  2b        Kompliziertereswort something    2.0
2  3c                Lehrerin in zu [Buch]   15.0
3  4d  Buch (Lehrerin) kompliziertereswort    5.0
```